# Wix velo to get user stripe info, active or not

Tags: jquery, velo

i am creating a functionality in wix website using velo it has default stripe payment method its course subscription website so when user has subscribed it shows him on his my subscription page "active"

I want just to track using velo if the current user has active subscription or not,

I tried to get user info using wix velo but i didn't find also i could not target the active element text